# Variable function out of scope in Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

In the attached code I tried to access the variable i outside the function, why does not it work?

```js
sum(1, 3);
console.log("i =", i); //i is undefined
```

Comment: How and where is 'i' defined? afaik variable hoisting occurs only for variables declared using 'var' and not using 'let'

Comment: Outside of which function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, you defined `i` in the function `sum` and no where else. That means it's not in the global scope, which means you cannot "see" what the value of `i` is in `sum` anywhere outside of the `sum` function.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Comment: Try to share docs using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/ because w3schools has some not up to date documentation.

Comment: It is indeed foolish of me to think that a variable within a function also seems outside, I'll fix the code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`i` is a variable, are you assigning it anywhere? If `sum` returns a value just assign it to `i` with `const i = sum(1, 3);`

then `` console.log(`i = ${i}`) ``

Comment: isnt it back tick (String literal) that should be used in log when trying to print ${} ?

Comment: Yep, just had to figure out how to escape backticks ;)